# How to draw a flowchart in latex using horizontal lines and no nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-styles, tikz-trees, tikz-cd

[image]

I need to draw a flowchart with no nodes and only horizontal lines.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)!  This site works best as a helping hand for when you get stuck with something. Questions like this, that look like "please do this thing for me" tend not to get answers because they require a great deal of effort on the part of the community. To make the most of this site, it would help if you made some substantive efforts please and show what you have done so far with a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). We are not paid to write code sadly.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!! A starting point: `\documentclass[tikz,border=1.618]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick]       (-0.5,0) -- (5,0);
\draw              (-0.5,2) -- (3,2);
\draw[latex-latex] (0,0) -- (0,2) node[midway,right,text width=1cm] {O\&M COST};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`.

Comment: One would want to ask why the no nodes requirement is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

As starting point is used @Juan Castaño comment. Writing a real text in edge quotes I left to you:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                quotes}
 
\begin{document} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every edge/.style = {draw, Straight Barb-Straight Barb},
every edge quotes/.style = {auto=right, inner xsep=2mm,
                            align=left} 
                        ]
\draw[thick]    (0,0)  -- ++ (9,0)
                (0,4)  -- ++ (3,0)
                (0,8)  -- ++ (5,0)
                (0,10) -- ++ (8,0); 
\draw   (0,2) -- ++ (2,0)
        (0,6) -- ++ (3,0); 
\path   (0.2,0) edge["O\&M\\ COST"]         ++ (0,2)
        (0.2,2) edge["Captital\\charges"]   ++ (0,2)
        (0.2,4) edge["text\\text"]          ++ (0,2)
        (0.2,6) edge["text\\text"]          ++ (0,2)
        (0.2,8) edge["text\\text"]          ++ (0,2)
%
        (2.8,0)   edge["FULL\\SUPPLY\\COST"]    ++ (0,4)
        (4.8,0)   edge["FULL\\ECONOMIC\\COST"]  ++ (0,8)
        (7.8,0)   edge["text\\text"]        ++ (0,10)
        ; 
    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```